# When a pokemon shows up in Sightings, at maximum how far away is it?

Tags: pokemon-go

Someone told me they are within a 100 meter radius, but I thought I read somewhere that it's 200. I can't find the article now, and it might have been referring to something else.

Comment: The "Nearby" system was *replaced* by the "Sightings" system. I may just be reading it wrong, but they do not coexist within the game.

Comment: @Ben My above screenshot shows both Nearby and Sightings. I'm on the current Android version (0.41.4).

Comment: @Ben the nearby system shown in the screenshot is the beta version that Niantic has been working on since the sightings feature was first introduced in early August. AFAIK, though, it was only available to users on the west coast.

Answer (score 2):

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wm0nd/question_whats_the_maximum_distance_a_pokemon/), users are generally supportive of the 200m radius.

> Through Ingress and verifying pokemon spawns in my neighborhood, the limit seems to be 200m in any direction.

[This article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/davidthier/2016/08/11/nearby-tracker-tracking-how-sightings-works-in-pokemon-go/#473af4456ad3) also supports the 200m radius:

> On a basic level, it’s showing you the Pokémon in an approximately 200 meter radius from where you’re standing

From [this post](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-go-tracker-0-33-0-update-sightings-guide/), it looks like the tracking distance has been set to 200m since the update the introduced "Sightings" as a replacement for the old "Nearby".

> The tracking area is back to a 200m radius around you, enabling the players to go for a quick walk and actually capture the Pokemon they’re after

From personal experience, I support the 200m radius as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon on your Sightings are a maximum of 200m away from your current location. I have no idea where that person got 100m, but I've confirmed countless times in my own travels that it's 200m.

Your screenshot also shows Nearby Pokemon, which are within a small radius of the Pokestop displayed next to the Pokemon, presumably 20m so they spawn when you're on top of the Pokestop. I can't confirm that, though, because I'm part of the 99.9% of the world that have yet to receive that feature.